# Why do these addition statements produce different results in ocaml?

Tags: integer, operators, ocaml, addition

All the documentation I can find for OCAML agrees that the "+" operator is used only for integer addition. I have a function that needs to increment an integer with each recursive call. The function definition:

```
let rec lst_act x lst c = ...
```

The original recursive call within that function:

```
(lst_act x t curr+1)
```

This function wasn't working as intended and I truly had no idea why. I decided to change the recursive call to this:

```
(list_act x t (curr + 1))
```

and voila, it worked. I don't understand how these statements are different, if the + operator is used only for integer addition in ocaml.

Could someone please explain the difference, and what each of those uses of the "+" operator does? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function application has higher precedence than +, so the first way you wrote it is equivalent to:

```
((lst_act x t curr) + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that function application has higher precedence (binds more strongly) than binary operators. Hence your expression

```
lst_act x t curr+1
```

is parsed as

```
(lst_act x t curr) + 1
```

and not as

```
lst_act x t (curr+1)
```

as you seem to have assumed. How that code behaves depends on the rest of your program; I cannot say much about that. In any case it is the same addition operator `+`, but applied to  something different.

Incidentally, the choice of precedence is the same as in everyday formulae:

```
sin(x) + cos(x)
```

is parsed as `(sin(x)) + (cos(x))` not as `(sin(x+cos))(x)` or `sin((x+cos)(x))` or anything else. Only that in OCaml, the parenthesis are optional in function application, so that it is equivalent to

```
sin x + cos x
```

(To prevent nitpicks: In order for the above to typecheck, `sin` and `cos` are not the ones from `Pervasives` which operate on `float`.)